# ThinkPad X1 Yoga 3rd Gen on Ubuntu 20.04, stylus calibration erratic

Tags: gnome, 20.04, thinkpad, wacom, stylus

Using a 3rd Generation ThinkPad X1 Yoga with 1440p display, the stylus calibration in default GNOME on Ubuntu 20.04 is erratic and unreliable. Trying to calibrate the stylus in the GNOME Settings Wacom section often results in the stylus being wildly miscalibrated (so the cursor is a quarter of screen away from the actual stylus).

I seem to eventually, after logging and logging out, switching between X11 and Wayland, and trying calibration several times to be able to get the stylus to recalibrate, but it's unclear what actually gets it to calibrate properly or why it so badly miscalibrates so often.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug in the GNOME Control Center. I would file an issue at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/ which describes the problem and the developers may be able to help. It would help them to know if you have any external displays connected (along with their resolution and layout) or if only the Yoga's internal display is present.

Comment: no external displays